# How were Power Bank limits decided by airlines?

Tags: batteries, power-electronics

Why is a 160Wh power bank considered safe to carry on board, but not 170Wh, for example? What defines this maximum safety limit, how was it determined? Obviously airlines across the globe have agreed that this limit is sufficient, but what make it sufficient (or if they are not sufficient in your opinion, why are they not sufficient)?

Comment: Probably by the amount of Lithium, which is 0.08g per Wh (IIRC)

Comment: @AlexandervonWernherr: really depends on the cells. The limit is probably rathre arbitrary, just like 100ml of liquid is "safe".

Comment: I have a mental picture of a committee meeting, shrimp cocktails and lots of fancy business cars being tossed around before pushing it to a sub-committee who hands back a suggested level.

Comment: @winny We had to cut the shrimps, due to increasing allergic reactions :o

Comment: possibly they considered the capacity of a typical fire extinguisher.

Comment: @AlexandervonWernherr It probably has nothing to do with the lithium; what burns in a Li-Ion battery fire is the flammable electrolyte, not the lithium.

Comment: Good thing all my power banks run on mAh and not Wh.

Answer (score 4):

The [FAA did tests](https://www.fire.tc.faa.gov/pdf/TC-15-59.pdf) after a [recommendation of the NTSB](https://www.ntsb.gov/news/press-releases/Pages/PR20140522.aspx) issued after a fire incident.
[Presentation of the results of the test.](https://www.icao.int/APAC/Meetings/2015%20WorkshopLithium/FAA_lithium_battery_update_July_2015_DGP.pdf)

Basically they measured the gas emission from thermal runaway in the cells. Which is the dangerous part, as it is the gasses could cause the explosions.
I cannot find the motivation for the 100Ah limit in this research.

If you know how much gas is emitted from cells you can estimate how much cells you need for an explosive or dangerous mixture, in say, the overhead storage.